# Deleting CKRecord: Record delete would violate validating reference, rejecting update

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I simply try to delete `CKRecord`. Before I assigned it as a parent and reference to another ckrecord like this:

```
    let rID = CKRecordID(recordName: territory.identifier, zoneID: territory.recordZoneID)
    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Territory", recordID: rID)

    if let territoryGroup = territoryGroup {
        let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: territoryGroup.identifier, zoneID: CloudAssistant.shared.zone.zoneID)
        record.parent = CKReference(recordID: recordID, action: .none)
        record["territoryGroup"] = CKReference(recordID: recordID, action: .none)
    }
```

and the error is following:

> "Error deleting record : Record delete would violate validating reference ([C1A31F1D-914F-4007-8C8B-73FC0503C798, ...]), rejecting update"

This was intended to delete record without deleting its child records, and this is why I set there action `.none` instead of `.deleteSelf`.

What is wrong?

The same in dashboard:

[image]

For corresponding reference record there is a good setup:

[image]

As you can see delete Self is not selected. Am I missing something? For me, it should delete it without problem.

Comment: Settint parent property at CKRecord create a hierarchy of your records. I suppose that no matter if you choose .none or .deleteSelf as action, the hierarchy has been set. Try to comment that line, because you have the hierarchy done by youself with the territoryGroup record property. Maybe this works...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same error when I set the parent of the record with `setParent(parentRecordID)` and also created a `CKReference` with `.none`. It looks like if you set the parent, you have to use `.deleteSelf` on the standard reference. However, from what I can tell, setting the parent is only necessary if you want to use `CKShare`. I wrote more about it [here](https://medium.com/@blwinters/cloudkit-parent-references-9b052aede67d).

Answer (score 1):

The way around this is to set another reference as an attribute that's NOT parent. This reference has .deleteSelf on.

See this answer

[Cannot delete CKRecords with `.parent` set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56796246/1712184)